# Magento2 password algorythm

Tags: magento-2.1, password

I want to use just 5 digit password instead of Caps lock number small character and more.
I want to just use 5 lengh it can be anything like 12345 or abcde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable password validation from the admin panel for that go to

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration
```

in `Password Options` section there is a field `Number of Required Character Classes` 
set `1` in that field and in `Minimum Password Length` set `5` and save the configuration.